# If the serie converges in probability

Tags: probability

Suppose $m$ is a strictly increasing smooth function, $x_0$ an arbitrarily chosen real number and $\{e_n\}$ is a set of identically and independent distributed random variable with zero mean and finite variance.
$$y_n=m(x_n)+e_n\quad x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{cy_n}{n}$$
And the question is to prove that $x_n\to x^*$ in probability where $x^*$ is the zero point of $m$, i.e. $m(x^*)=0$.

So far I have made no progress. I think the key point is to deal with non-convergence of $1/n$.

Comment: It's a typo. I have made an edit. Thanks.

Comment: The series is not necessarily converge. It's actually a Newton method with some randomness. If the original method converges not, with specific example one can show it also doesn't converge.